# Getting committer emails

Tags: email, github-api, git-commit, github3.py

I am trying to get the email addresses of the committers of a project to specific files. After creating a query that finds the code files in a list of repos matching specific criteria, I get the correct results in the form of code_results (of type CodeSearchResult). Now to try access the commit information, I do the following

```
for code_result in code_results:
            repository = code_result.repository
            file_path = code_result.path
            commits = repository.commits(path=file_path)
            for commit in commits:
                if commit.committer is not None:
                    print commit.committer
```

The problem is that trying to get the email through commit.committer.email always returns None even though the documentation says that a commit contains the committer's email. I also tried author instead of committer since the documentation says the author is a dict containing the email, but I'm not sure what the dict keys are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of GitHub's endpoints that return listings only return partial objects in the listing. It's odd that committer or author would ever be None, honestly, but you could try doing:

```
for commit in commits:
    commit = commit.refresh()
    if commit.committer is not None:
        print commit.committer
```

That said, in testing this against github3.py, I can't reproduce this problem. I did

```
repository = github3.repository('sigmavirus24', 'github3.py')
for commit in repository.commits(path='setup.py'):
     print(commit.committer)
     print(commit.author)
```

And with the exception of one commit, both were always present. That was from [this commit](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/1d45fee8471531c98bdb610579e94c756b3cff1c/setup.py) where the user didn't have a GitHub account. That said, I can then inspect `commit.commit` to get the raw data about the git commit object itself. That has both a `committer` and `author` object, see

```
>>> commit.commit.committer
{u'date': u'2013-09-05T02:23:17Z', u'name': u'Barry Morrison and Ian Cordasco', u'email': u'graffatcolmingov+bmorriso@gmail.com'}
>>> commit.commit.author
{u'date': u'2013-09-05T02:23:17Z', u'name': u'Barry Morrison and Ian Cordasco', u'email': u'graffatcolmingov+bmorriso@gmail.com'}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the check for None is because (similar to that one commit case), there were some commits where the committer or author were None which is why I had to have this check. However, my question was actually about getting the email address. This is the one field that I find to *always* be None when you do commit.committer.email

Comment: Well you can always get it from `commit.commit.committer['email']`. If you don't want to do that then calling `commit.committer.refresh()` should do the trick if the user has a public email address.

Comment: Thanks! Both ways work and give me the information I want.